Langgraph: Add a new state in graph
I have been tinkering with the langgraph supervisor multi agent example: https://github.com/langchain-ai/langgraph/blob/main/examples/multi_agent/agent_supervisor.ipynb.
Let's say I have the below code:
def create_agent(llm: ChatOpenAI, tools: list, system_prompt: str):
    prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
        [
            (
                "system",
                system_prompt,
            ),
            MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="messages"),
            MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="agent_scratchpad"),
        ]
    )
    agent = create_openai_tools_agent(llm, tools, prompt)
    executor = AgentExecutor(agent=agent, tools=tools, return_intermediate_steps=True, verbose=True)
    return executor

I would like to have the agent state as defined below:
# The agent state is the input to each node in the graph
class AgentState(TypedDict):
    # The annotation tells the graph that new messages will always
    # be added to the current states
    messages: Annotated[Sequence[BaseMessage], operator.add]
    # The 'next' field indicates where to route to next
    next: str
    # resolution
    resolution: bool ## This here is what I want to add.

Basically, I want to have the agent and it's tools to also respond with a "resolution" value to say whether the query was able to be resolved or not (True or False).
I changed the agent_node() code like below:
def agent_node(state, agent, name):
    print("\n***************\n")
    print(state)
    print("\n***************\n")
    result = agent.invoke(state)
    return {"messages": [HumanMessage(content=result["output"], name=name), additional_kwargs={"intermediate_steps": result["intermediate_steps"]})]}

Running this prints the below output:
***************

{'messages': [HumanMessage(content='SOME QUERY HERE')], 'next': 'FOO', 'resolution': None}

***************

The agent supervisor, from the example above, I have left untouched
What do I need to change in my agent system prompt, supervisor or wherever so that I get the desired output of having the "resolution" also populate? Am I even going in the right direction to achieve what I want?

Each node will emit an update on the state when leaving the node. You can add in the return statement the field of AgentState that you need to update:
def agent_node(state, agent, name):
    print("\n***************\n")
    print(state)
    print("\n***************\n")
    result = agent.invoke(state)
    return {
        "messages": [HumanMessage(content=result["output"], name=name),
        "resolution": True,
        additional_kwargs={"intermediate_steps": result["intermediate_steps"]})]
    }

Check out this link https://langchain-ai.github.io/langgraph/concepts/low_level/#state

Let me play around with this. Thank you for the pointer to the Langgraph doc as well.
